# Find a function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $A^*df=0$

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, exterior-algebra

> Let $A : \mathbb{R}^2 = \{(u,v)\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3=\{(x,y,z)\}$ be given by
>
> $A(u,v)=(u,v,F(u,v))$
>
> Find a function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $A^*df=0$.

I have tried $A^*df=d(A^*f)=d(f \circ A)=df(u,v,F(u,v))$, which gives that

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}du + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}dv+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dF=0$.

I cannot see how to use this to now to find an $f$.

I would like to look for a sufficient and or neceesary condition for a solution and not just find some semi trivial solution.

Comment: $A^*f$ should be a constant.

Comment: @user8268 What's the meaning of $*$ at $A*df$ please?

Comment: $A^*df$ is the pullback of $df$. $A^*df=df \circ A$ albeit applied on slightly different vectors on either side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**: The image of $A$ is a level surface of the function $f(x,y,z)=z-F(x,y)$.

Comment: Could you describe further how you can see this, I thought this was true but I cant explain it properly

Comment: Maybe this will help: $A(u,v) = (u,v,f(u,v)) = (x,y,z)$. Now equate coordinates.